# Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 3 supplied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I am trying to migrate data from CSV to SQLite database.
The CSV has 3 columns and table has only 2. I tried to pop() out the last element in the list returned by row.split(',') but it is giving a different error

[Github link to csv](https://github.com/theforage/forage-walmart-task-4/blob/main/data/shipping_data_1.csv)

code:

```
seen = set();
with open("E:/Forage/Walmart/task4/shipping_data_1.csv",'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        if row in seen: continue
        
    seen.add(row)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO product values(?,?)",row.split(',').pop())
    con.commit();
con.close()
```

error:
when

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO product values(?,?)",row.split(',')); is used

-->Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 3 supplied.
```

and

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO product values(?,?)",row.split(',').pop()); is used

-->Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 8 
supplied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pop() is not what you want (it returns the popped element - the third column, and then Python is trying to iterate over letters in the string). You need to use slicing instead. If you want to keep the first two columns, do

```py
row.split(',')[:2]
```